# How to learn about the Eclipse Platform

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

What is the up-to-date way to learn about the Eclipse Platform, RCP...? I found these [books](http://www.informit.com/imprint/series_detail.aspx?st=61273), but they were last published 3 years ago. Is that considered eons ago in the Eclipse world? What is the canonical Introductory Guide for understanding Eclipse principles nowadays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are now two ways to do Eclipse RCP development, the Eclipse 3.x way where the older books are probably still relevant, and the Eclipse 4 'e4' way which features a new application model, direct injection and CSS styling. For an introduction to e4 RCP development see: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html the author also has an e-book version of the tutorial.